# how to call function on jquery hover()

Tags: jquery, hover

I am trying to call function into jquery `hover()`.
First I'm creating function `objIn()` to pass value from `hover()` and it works.
After `mousenter` to object, I create flag to run second function, but I have problem when passing parameter into function `testObj()`.

How I can pass value from jquery `hover()` to my function I create?

```js
var objHover = $('.main ul li a, .content-wrap .content');

var flag = 'true';
var mainAnchor;

function objIn(mainAnchor) {
  var mainData = $('.main li a[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
  var contentData = $('.content-wrap .content[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');

  function testObj(dataItem) {
    if (dataItem == 'true') {
      contentData.addClass('active');
      contentData.siblings().addClass('hidden');
      mainData.addClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else if (dataItem == 'false') {
      mainData.removeClass('active');
      contentData.removeClass('active');
      contentData.siblings().removeClass('hidden');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  }
}

objHover.hover(
  function() {
    flag = 'true';
    mainAnchor = $(this).data('hover');
    objIn(mainAnchor);
    testObj(flag);
  },
  function() {
    flag = 'false';
    mainAnchor = $(this).data('hover');
    objIn(mainAnchor);
    testObj(flag);
  });
```

```css
.content-wrap{
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content{
  padding: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main li a.active,
.content.active{
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.hidden{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.content.hidden{
 background-color: gray;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item1">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item2">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item3">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item4">item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item5">item 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content-wrap">
  <div class="content red" data-hover="item1">content 1</div>
  <div class="content green" data-hover="item2">content 2</div>
  <div class="content blue" data-hover="item3">content 3</div>
  <div class="content purple" data-hover="item4">content 4</div>
  <div class="content brown" data-hover="item5">content 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: testobj function  is inside the objIn function so it's throwing testObj is not defined

Comment: What is the reason of nesting `testObj` function inside `objIn` function?

Comment: objIn(mainAnchor,dataItem);  function objIn(mainAnchor,dataItem) {  function testObj(dataItem) { }   } you can pass like this and use like this

Comment: Is it posibble to enter nested function? or is there another way how to do it? Reason I wrote my code because I have no idea how to make this into global function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written function `testObj` inside another function hence not reachable from outside. Also define `mainData` and `contentData` as global so that it will be available in `testObj` function.
please put it outside it as shown below

```
var mainData;
var contentData;
function objIn(mainAnchor) {
    mainData = $('.main li a[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
    contentData = $('.content-wrap .content[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
}

function testObj(dataItem) {
    if (dataItem == 'true') {
      contentData.addClass('active');
      contentData.siblings().addClass('hidden');
      mainData.addClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else if (dataItem == 'false') {
      mainData.removeClass('active');
      contentData.removeClass('active');
      contentData.siblings().removeClass('hidden');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  }
```

Comment: thats what I look for, I just don't get it how to make them global. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: happy to help you :)